# How to route 2 parameters to a controller?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

This seems really basic but i can't get the hang of it.

I'm trying to send more then one parameter to a method in the controller, like this :

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/subjects/3/state
```

This is the routings i've tried :

```
$route['subjects/(:num)'] = 'subjects/view/$1';
$route['subjects/(:num)/{:any}'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2';
```

the method accepted 2 paremeters :

```
public function view($slug, $id = null){

}
```

but i seem to get a 404. How can i get this to work? i need the view method to always accept 1 parameter and optional other parameters.

**NOTE** : I am including the url helper.

Comment: try this $route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2'; will work

Comment: This has worked, the problem was i used {} instead of (). Thanks submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you have problem with your route brackets just change it from {} to () brackets will work

from

```
$route['subjects/(:num)/{:any}'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2';
```

to

```
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2';
```

Comment: Doing that got me stuck on an endless loops of refreshing so i guess something is wrong here...

Comment: Eric, are you still having an issue because this should work for your situation. Is there other custom routing going on?

Comment: Ya i solved it, the problem was with URLS of ajax called i made that caused infinte loop but i fixed those. Thanks!

Comment: How can we pass multiple parameters for routing?

Comment: for multiple parameter try this $route['subjects/(:any)'] = 'subject/view';

Comment: how can i access the variables in controller? i tried using `($id = null) {
        print_r($id);
        print_r($_GET);die();` but both didnt return any value

Comment: these parameters are part of URL not URL query string, you can access them with CI uri library segment like $this->uri->segment(1); 1 is number of segment you want to access read more here https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 10):

Always maintain your routing rules

like

```
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2/$3';
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2';
```

always follow this pattern for routing

if you add like this

```
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2';
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2/$3/$4';
$route['subjects/(:num)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'subjects/view/$1/$2/$3';
```

then always first condition will be true every time.

also refer this link --> [codeigniter routing rules](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: how can i access the variables in controller? i tried using ($id = null) { print_r($id); print_r($_GET);die(); but both didnt return any value

Answer (score 3):

I once tried this URI pattern

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'welcome/list1/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'welcome/list1/$1/$2';

$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'welcome/list2/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'welcome/list2/$1/$2/$3';

$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'welcome/list3/$1/$2/$3';
```

but it didnt worked ... so I replaced it with regular expression

`([a-z 0-9 -]+)` replaced `(:any)`
and
`([0-9]+)` replaced `(:num)`

so it became

```
$route['([a-z 0-9 -]+)'] = 'welcome/list1/$1';
$route['([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([0-9]+)'] = 'welcome/list1/$1/$2';

$route['([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([a-z 0-9 -]+)'] = 'welcome/list2/$1/$2';
$route['([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([0-9]+)'] = 'welcome/list2/$1/$2/$3';

$route['([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([a-z 0-9 -]+)/([a-z 0-9 -]+)'] = 'welcome/list3/$1/$2/$3';
```

And it worked for me :)

In order to access the variables in your controllers, you can assign any parameter in the function.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function list($first, $second)
    {
        var_dump($first);
        var_dump($second);
    }
}
```

Comment: Outstanding Solution

Comment: thanks. I have been using this for a while, it works well.

Comment: how can i access the variables in controller? i tried using ($id = null) { print_r($id); print_r($_GET);die(); but both didnt return any value

Comment: @guradio - I have edited the solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple segments with the `(.+)` parameter like this:

> **$route['method/(.+)'] = 'controller/method/$1';**

In that case the $1 will contain everything past method/. In general I think its discouraged to use this since you should know what is being passed and handle it appropriately but there are times (.+) comes in handy. For example if you don’t know how many parameters are being passed this will allow you to capture all of them. Also remember, you can set default parameters in your methods like this:

> **public function method($param=''){}**

So that if nothing is passed, you still have a valid value.

You can also pass to your index method like this:

> **$route['method/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/index/$1/$2';**
>
> **$route['method/(:any)'] = 'controller/method/index/$1';**

Obviously these are just examples. You can also include folders and more complex routing but that should get you started.